# RE: Conexión Spring SSO con diferentes AD

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, activedirectory, saml

**Reformulo la pregunta por si así queda mas claro de entender :**

No se si se puede hacer con Spring en una web que tiene sus usuarios, usuarios externos necesitan entrar con sus propios usuarios de Active Directory.

un SSO SAML con Java Spring Multicliente.

entonces, desde nuestra web se entra en:

- https://app.web.com/sso/servidor_1/login

  - en este caso ingresan las personas que estén registradas en el servidor 1
- https://app.web.com/sso/servidor_2/login

  - en este caso ingresan las personas que estén registradas en el servidor 2
- https://app.web.com/sso/servidor_3/login

  - en este caso ingresan las personas que estén registradas en el servidor 3
- luego de ingresar van a una sección donde se le asigna un token para que ingrese a la web principal
- y así sucesivamente contra n servidores

lo que hemos conseguido es hacer un SSO con un solo servidor, pero no con varios servidores,
y que cambien dependiendo de la URL

Esto es posible con Spring SAML.

Ejemplo practico,

> Hay una web de música, y los trabajadores de CocaCola quieren entrar
> y los de pepsi también entonces tanto CocaCola como Pepsi tiene sus
> propios AD (Active directory) con los usuarios
>
> entonces la web de música tiene esta URL:
> https://webmusic.com/sso/cocacola/login o
> https://webmusic.com/sso/pepsi/login (u o más urls, fanta, redbull)
>
> y estas rutas redirigen al AD pertinente, luego cuando el AD da el
> OK, se crea y redirige a la web de Musica con el nuevo token
> creado a partir  de los datos que entrego el AD.

---

> Estoy probando con Java Spring
>
> Y estoy intentando hacer un SSO contra Active Directory , he
> conseguido conectar uno, de esta manera
>
> > SamlApplication .java ``` Java package com.test.sso;
>
> import java.security.Key; import java.util.Base64; import
> java.util.Date;
>
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value; import
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; import
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication; import
> org.springframework.security.core.Authentication; import
> org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
> import
> org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
> import
> org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; import
> org.springframework.ui.Model; import
> org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping; import
> org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable; import
> org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
>
> import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts; import
> io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm; // !!! deprecation import
> io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
>
> @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @SpringBootApplication @Controller
> public class SamlApplication {
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
> SpringApplication.run(SamlApplication.class, args);     }
>
> @RequestMapping("/")    public String index() {         return "index";     }
>
> ```
> // esto no funciona, da igual lo que venga en iden, siempre carga el mismo AD     @GetMapping("/hello/{iden}")    public String
> ```
>
> helloUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal user,
> Model model,          @PathVariable("iden") String iden) throws Exception {
>
> ```
>   model.addAttribute("name", user.getName());
>   model.addAttribute("iden", iden);
>
>   Authentication authentication =
> ```
>
> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
>
> ```
>   if (!authentication.isAuthenticated()) throw new Exception("Access
> ```
>
> denied.");
>
> ````
>   System.out.println("iden" + iden);
>
>   return "hello"; // ResponseEntity.ok("hello");  } } ```
> ````
>
> > SecurityConfiguration.java
>
> ````java
> import static
> org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;
>
> import java.util.Arrays;
>
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import
> org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; import
> org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration; import
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
> import
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
> import
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
> import
> org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
> import
> org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistration;
> import
> org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
> import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain; import
> org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration; import
> org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource; import
> org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
>
> @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @EnableWebSecurity @Configuration
> @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true) public class
> SecurityConfiguration {
>
>   @Autowired  IdpService idpService;
>
>   @Bean   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity
> http) throws Exception {      http
>               .cors(withDefaults())
>               .csrf(csrf -> csrf
>                       .disable())
>               .authorizeRequests(
>                       authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
>               .saml2Login(withDefaults());        return http.build();    }
>
>     @Bean     protected RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrations()            throws Exception {
>
>       RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistration
>               .withRegistrationId("azure-saml")
>               .assertingPartyDetails(party -> party
>                       .entityId(____ENTITY_ID_AD_______)
>                       .singleSignOnServiceLocation(____SingleSignOnServiceLocation_AD_______)
>                       .wantAuthnRequestsSigned(false)
>                       .verificationX509Credentials(c -> c.add(____URL__Credential_CERT_AD_______)))
>               .build();
>
>       return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registration);
>   }
>
>   @Bean   CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
>       CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
>
>       configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
>
>       configuration.setAllowedOrigins(
>               Arrays.asList(null,
>                       "https://*", "http://*",
>                       "https://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8080/**",
>                       "https://login.microsoftonline.com", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/**",
>                       "https://sts.windows.net", "https://sts.windows.net/**"));      configuration
>               .setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "TRACE"));
>
>       UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
> UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
>       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
>
>       return source;  } } ```
>
> Esto funciona conectado a un AD SAML, no si es la mejor manera, lo que
> estoy intentando ahora hacer, es para muchos AD SMAL, pero no veo
> forma de como, soy nuevo usando Spring, he buscado y consultado con la
> IA tambien pero no llego a ningun punto claro, falla todo lo que
> pruebo.
>
> la idea es si un usuario entra en 
> - https://_web_/sso/_server-1_/login -> llamara al AD 1 para buscar susu usuarios
> - https://_web_/sso/_server-2_/login -> llamara al AD 2 para buscar susu usuarios
>
> y así continuamente, para futuros servidores, su propia url y llame a
> la configuracion de turno,
>
> no se si esto es posible. 
>
> gracias.
> ````